# Forward emails from domain to another email at different domain?

Tags: email, debian, pop3

I run a small Debian server at home, and it's hosting two websites. I would also like to have emails received on this domain, to this server, but sent on to our real email addresses. Essentially, if they email `anything@domain.com`, it forwards to `canadianluke@otherdomain.com`, on a different domain. Can this be done, or do I need a FULL Email server program on my server to do so?

My registrar is Canspace.ca, and I do not see any Mail options, except to specify my MX Record, which I would point to my server. Currently, there is no email being *hosted* on my server, but the goal is that any emails destined for my domain name go to my regular email address.

I emailed the Registrar, and they stated that unless I buy their hosting package for the website and everything else, there are no mail services offered, other than pointing the MX record somewhere. So, back to the original question, what is the smallest thing I can do to my Debian-based server to get mail that is sent to it, automatically forwarded to my main account, without storing it on my server?

Comment: I'm surprised your domain manager (the company that takes care of your domain records) doesn't offer this, probably for free. Namecheap has free email forwarding.

Comment: Hmm... I'll double check the control panel, but I don't think it was offered. With the name, I get control of the dns, and that seems to be about it

Comment: He's indicating that the server is running at home.  I don't see any mention of a hosting company (yet).  So it comes down to his ISP, and his connection.  Unless, of course, more details can be provided...  This question really, *really* needs clarifications.

Comment: @AveryPayne Someone or something needs to be hosting the authoritative DNS server. It is entirely reasonable to assume that the DNS hosting is provided by the registrar or reseller. Many DNS hosts also provide extra services, often including email forwarding (where they add MX records pointing to their own servers), which is what allquixotic is talking about. Your answer makes the assumption that MX records are already pointing at the local server, which is another approach. Either is valid.

Comment: Updated the question, hopefully that helps, @allquixotic, Avery and Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have this semi-solved. Let me go through what I did.

First off, I had to install a service to *receive* the emails; I chose postfix, as per the suggestion of Avery Payne. I followed the directions [on Debian's website](https://wiki.debian.org/Postfix) to getting it installed and working *locally* inside my network. I was able to send mail and receive mail, but not using the FQDN. I figured this was a DNS issue or a port forwarding issue.

For setting up postfix:

```
apt-get install postfix
cat /var/log/mail.log
postconf -e "myorigin = example.com"
postconf -e "myhostname=server1.example.com"
postconf -e "relay_domains = example.com, example2.com, example3.com"
postfix reload
```

Then, I tested it locally:

```
$ telnet localhost 25
>Trying 127.0.0.1...
>Connected to localhost.localdomain.
>Escape character is '^]'.
>220 server1.example.com ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
mail from:<you@youremail.com>
rcpt to:<user@example.com>
data
To: user@example.com
From: you@youremail.com
Subject: Hey my first email
This is my first email on debian postfix after installing configuring it.
It was easy.
```

I ended the message and sent it by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I then exited, and checked my mail on my account:

```
mail
>You have 1 new mail!
```

I read it and deleted it. I then tried the instructions above to forward the messages, but it would not send out. Fine, maybe something was blocked. I tried to `telnet mail.example.com 25`, and I could connect from my cell (not on the Wifi). So, I'm guessing Shaw (my ISP) isn't blocking it. I sent an email to my address, but the server would not receive it. I came back onto the Wifi, and it sent the mail! So there is something blocking it, but that's going to need to be another question.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to do this.

First, let me preface this with the following: while it is *assumed* that you have an email service installed, you didn't indicate that it is the case.  All examples here *assume* that you have the service installed.  There are other methods that do not require a full email server, but they are special cases and you typically have immediate delivery with no mail queue.

Debian typically comes with a mail transfer agent already installed, which is some version of Exim (dependent on your version of Debian).  You have the option of using other MTAs, such as Sendmail, Qmail, or Postfix, by installing them.  I am most familiar with Postfix out of that list, so my answers will have a slant towards using/configuring Postfix.

### .forward files

The first / easiest / cheesy way to do this is to place a `.forward` file in the home directory of the account receiving the email.  The `.forward` file consists of a single line, like so:

```
someuser@someserver.net
```

When email is delivered, the `.forward` file is checked, and if found, the contents used to forward the email on to the address indicated.  This is originally meant to forward email temporarily to a new address, back in Ye Olde Days when real users were hosted on real *nix-style systems.  In your case, it most likely won't work because (a) I doubt you really have a user account set up that corresponds to the address, (b) the "standard" is *supposed* to be supported by all MTAs, but there is no guarantee, and (b) the website server's address mismatches the email server's address to begin with, so there are other disconnects that prevent this from being a smooth transition.

Of course, it goes without mention, that *anything*@somedomain.net will not be forwarded; it wants a full, resolvable address.  So, **this won't work for you**.

### Using an MDA

**M** ail **D** elivery **A** gents are specifically meant to make deliveries to local mailboxes.  Based on the limited wording you have provided, I can only assume that you require delivery of the email to a different server.  So **this isn't for you, either.**

### Using an MTA

The second option is to install a **M** ail **T** ransport **A** gent, what people typically call "email service".  Most of these typically come with the ability to re-route messages based on a series of lookups.  In the case of Postfix, you can route all messages for a given domain to another address.  Any message that matches this rule is re-injected into Postfix's pipeline, resulting in a delivery to the new address.  You can do this by creating a mapping for the address to your destination address, and then informing Postfix of the change.

Another advantage to using an MTA is that the message will be queued for delivery; if there is some issue (such as loss of connectivity to the Internet) the MTA will continue to attempt delivery until either the message is delivered, or a specified time-out has been reached, at which point the message will bounce.

**I recommend this approach.**  It not only provides a little robustness (using queues), it also provides flexibility (you can have several domains mapped this way).